# Schema Relationship Diagram For Student Database

Tags: mysql, laravel

Need advice trying to build Student Management Database using Laravel below is my Diagram need your advice if i'm doing the right way..

[image]

Comment: Can a user be both a staff member and a student?

Comment: What's the difference between points and score_user? In general, this looks overly complex to me, but I don't know your precise requirements

Comment: Nope each has different role to play..student can login check his scores attendance subjects , Staff can update all student information example. grades,subject class etc.. @LobsterBaz

Comment: @Strawberry points will represent as type of points example. EXAM , HOMEWORK, PARTICIPATION, ORAL, etc.. where value represent the allocated average in percentage like EXAM=50% then score user is the actual result like studen EXAM result=60points out of 50%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to provide a clear answer without knowing your application logic.

You should think in terms of "models" and "relations".

Here are a few suggestions:

---

- `User` has one `Role`. (This role can be student or staff or whatever row you have in your Role table along with the relevant properties).
- `Role` has many `User`.

---

- `User` has many `Class`
- `Class` has many `User`

(Many to many relationship: you will also need a `Class_User` pivot table)

---

- `Class` has one `Subject`
- `Subject` has many `Class`

---

- `Subject` has many `Assignment`
- `Assignment` has one `Subject` (score/points can be a column in Assignment table)

---

Etc.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove both User_Student and User_Staff and put student_id,
  staff_id into user model, because one user can be only link to one
  student, same for staff.
- Link Points to Class_Subject, because one
  subject can have multiple points for each class: i.e :     A subject
  Sub1, Class 1 : 5 pt,  Class 2 : 7pt, ...etc
- Link Score_user to
  Class_Subject, to have user's score for each class under each level.